# Prevent a file from being tracked by other branches

Tags: git

I have a `file.config` sitting in my master branch.
I want to create a **feature** branch from my **master** but I don't want my `file.config` to appear in it.

Knowing that I still want to keep track of the changes that happens to that file.

Is there a way of doing so?

EDIT: For the context, the `config.file` is a sort of "button" that deploys the code nested in the current branch in the production environment. That's why I don't want it to to be in any other branch than the "master", that limits the risks of human error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really, seriously, cannot get what you want in Git.  The reason is pretty fundamental: files are not tracked or untracked by virtue of being in some branch, or not in some branch.  What makes a file tracked (vs untracked) is its presence in (or absence from) the *index*.  At the same time, branch *names* merely identify *one particular commit*, with the one commit they identify being changeable at any time ... and each *commit* can be in *many* branches simultaneously.

These three facts—(1) tracked vs untracked being a property of the current *index* contents, hence not directly connected to any branch-name; (2) branch names move over time; (3) commits are in multiple branches—all interact in a fashion that's rather bad for your use case.

To understand these, you need to know how commits, the index, and the work-tree interact, what happens when you use `git checkout` with a branch name or a commit hash, and how branches get created and move around in general.  These are all tied into one big [Gordian Knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Knot) ... and the solution to your actual problem is similar: don't even try to untie the knot, just sidestep the whole mess by keeping instead a *prototype* of the configuration.  Have whatever process you use that needs it, build or obtain it as needed: this could be as simple as: *if I've just run `git checkout master`, copy the prototype into place; if I've just run a `git checkout` that takes me off `master`, remove the in-place copy, leaving only the prototype.*

(If you want to automate this, look into the `post-checkout` hook.)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to tell your local git that a particular file should never be changed using [update-index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index).  This will stop the file from showing up in `git status` and the like, while keeping it in the repository for everyone else.

It's important to note though that this change will happen in your local git, not in your branch.  So if you switch branches it will still be in effect, and you won't be able to push this change to a remote.

```
git update-index --skip-worktree file.config
```

And if you want changes to this file to show up in `git status` again, run:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree file.config
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the file from the other branches that you create from master *but* if you then merge them back into master, the file will be deleted in master (unless you go out of your way to avoid it, which is always possible). If those branches are to never be merged into master, just deleting the file from them will be fine.

The other problem that you might see if you decide to do it this way is that if the file is changed on master and then you merge master into your branch, you will get a tree conflict, which is to expect because the file is missing from your branches, so you would just tell git to remobve the file when it happens and then allow the merge to finish.